# You can't help but

Tags: phrase-usage

I know that there's a phrase "You can't help but do something". Eg. "You can't help but smile."

But is "You can't help but have your legs tremble" example viable? I mean does it sound off to an English speaker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You can't help but have your legs tremble" doesn't sound right, because when your legs tremble it is *involuntary* - you don't actually make it happen. The word "have" between you and your legs suggests that you are compelled to make them tremble. For example, "You can't help but have your mother make you a sandwich" doesn't make any sense - it suggests a compulsion on your part, but then your mother would have to voluntarily comply with it.

These might work:

- Your legs can't help but tremble
- You can't help but tremble

Comment: But isn't the same logic applied to "You can't help but tremble"? It's also involuntary

Comment: @Ilya Not really - "you can't help" means you have no control over. The word "have" in your example suggests that you *make* your legs tremble. That's what sounds wrong to me, as a BrEng speaker.

Comment: At college, in 1968, I couldn't help but go weak at the knees when the red-haired Irish girl smiled at me (we now have six grandchildren).